# Celery dynamic queue creation and routing

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to call a task and create a queue for that task if it doesn't exist then immediately insert to that queue the called task. I have the following code:

```
@task
def greet(name):
    return "Hello %s!" % name


def run():
    result = greet.delay(args=['marc'], queue='greet.1',
        routing_key='greet.1')
    print result.ready()
```

then I have a custom router:

```
class MyRouter(object):

    def route_for_task(self, task, args=None, kwargs=None):
        if task == 'tasks.greet':
            return {'queue': kwargs['queue'],
                    'exchange': 'greet',
                    'exchange_type': 'direct',
                    'routing_key': kwargs['routing_key']}
        return None
```

this creates an exchange called `greet.1` and a queue called `greet.1` but the queue is empty. The exchange should be just called `greet` which knows how to route a routing key like `greet.1` to the queue called `greet.1`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

When you do the following:

```
task.apply_async(queue='foo', routing_key='foobar')
```

Then Celery will take default values from the 'foo' queue in CELERY_QUEUES,
or if it does not exist then automatically create it using (queue=foo, exchange=foo, routing_key=foo)

So if 'foo' does not exist in CELERY_QUEUES you will end up with:

```
queues['foo'] = Queue('foo', exchange=Exchange('foo'), routing_key='foo')
```

The producer will then declare that queue, but since you override the routing_key,
actually send the message using `routing_key = 'foobar'`

This may seem strange but the behavior is actually useful for topic exchanges,
where you publish to different topics.

It's harder to do what you want though, you can create the queue yourself
and declare it, but that won't work well with automatic message publish retries.
It would be better if the queue argument to apply_async could support
a custom `kombu.Queue` instead that will be both declared and used as the destination.
Maybe you could open an issue for that at http://github.com/celery/celery/issues

Comment: I stopped worrying about creating queue manually, instead just spawn a new worker which creates queue and exchange automatically which made more sense to my problem. As always, thanks for the reply. :)